# Got invited to careers.stackoverflow, but I already have an account

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Earlier today, I was in one of my Stack Exchange profiles, and it asked me to fill some new data for new profile: job, tags, and if I'm currently looking for a job.

And an hour later I checked my email and see an invitation there to careers.stackoverflow for my **b@mail.com** email address. Which looks like a smooth transition from my previous actions. But, I already have a profile at Careers on my main Stack Overflow profile linked to **a@mail.com**. And when I follow the link, it automatically logged me in, and I see my name on top of the page which asks me if I want to accept invitation.

I think the problem here, is that I originally create that profile with email **a@mail.com**, and later switch it to have **b@mail.com** as the main contact email. So it looks like systems that sends invites checks only original emails Careers profile was created with, but it should probably check all emails linked to a Careers profile.

Comment: Looking into it, thanks for your report

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oops! We *were* checking for existing profiles, among other conditions, before sending Careers invitations... but we missed some parenthesis and ended up with a (a && b || c) expression. This has been fixed and pushed to production on build rev `2015.11.11.2970`. Thanks for your report <3

Comment: Good job on fixing this so fast. Those boolean logic bugs could be tricky to spot

Comment: Glad to see that even the genius devs at SO make these mundane mistakes, somehow it makes me feel better :-)